# How to append '\n' at the end of char*?

Tags: c++, string, append, escaping

Here's my code that shows what I'm trying to do but does not work.

```
#include <iostream>

char * getNewStr(char *str)
{
    size_t oldsize = strlen(str);
    size_t newsize = oldsize + 2;
    str = static_cast<char *>(realloc(str, newsize));
    str[oldsize] = '\n';
    str[oldsize + 1] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *str = const_cast<char *>("Hello World");
    char *newStr = getNewStr(str);
    std::cout << newStr << newStr;
    free(newStr);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the result to be

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

But currently, this crashes at the `realloc()` part.

How can I correct the function `getNewStr()` to make it work?

(P.S: The argument and return type for `getNewStr()` function should be `char *` as it is now. I don't want to use `std::string` in the function.)

Comment: If you use C++, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: `char *str = const_cast<char *>("Hello World");` No, no, no no.  **Never** cast away the const from a string literal.  It allows you to write the broken code that you have

Comment: You can only `realloc` things that were created with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @NathanOliver why not? then what's the alternative way in C++? It gives me warning without the `const_cast`.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @ZackLee If your goal is to modify a string literal, there is no work-around because it's not allowed in c++. Copy the string literal and modify the copy instead. `std::string` does everything you want to do here for you easily.

Comment: Obligatory "use std::string" remarks aside, you should use `malloc` (or even better `new char[newsize]`) instead of `realloc`. And then copy your string into the allocated memory with `memcpy` or `strcpy` or `std::copy`.

Comment: @ZackLee The C++ is to leave all this alone and use `std::string`.  If you don't want to do that then your code needs to look like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e5102ae1687e8f8)

Comment: @ZackLee `const char *str = "Hello World";` The reason string literals are `const` is because they live in read only memory and have static lifetime, modifying them invokes undefined behaviour. (Which can produce anything from the program running fine, to a crash, to a sentient ai)

Comment: @NathanOliver Hey, I think your comment should be the answer. Btw, Can I replace `for` parts with `strcpy(newstr, str);` in your code? Do you think it's correct?

Comment: using string really helps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you should probably make use of string data type and can achieve what you are expecting in a lot simpler way like below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string getNewStr(string & str)
{
    str.append("\r\n");
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string str = "Hello World";
    string newStr = getNewStr(str);
    std::cout << newStr << newStr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [documentation of realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), there is the following line:

> Reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with a call to free or realloc. Otherwise, the results are undefined.

Since the character pointer from the string constant was not obtained from a `*alloc` function, it is invalid to pass it to realloc. In this case the undefined behaviour manifests as a crash, but this is not guaranteed by the standard (hence "undefined").

In this case, you should pass a copy of the string to the function, and remember to free it when you are done with it.

Really though, if you're using C++, then you should be using std::string.